# Filter javascript object with key

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have a javascript object like this,

```
{
  apple: { .... },
  orange: { ... },
  mango: { ... },
  jackfruit: { ... }
}
```

and I want to grenerate a new object from this object. I want values of cetain keys only, like  `['mango', apple' ]`
Is there any filter function to filter these items from this object using this array?

My resulting object should be like

```
{
  mango: { ... }
  apple: { ... }
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).filter(r => ['mango','apple'].indexOf(r) > -1).map(i => obj[i]);` should be enough.

Comment: @Pranav, it's working for you ?

Comment: @briosheje it is not working. It returns array of values of mango and apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the Ramda library,

```
R.pick(['a', 'd'], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {a: 1, d: 4}
R.pick(['a', 'e', 'f'], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {a: 1}
```

> See http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick

Answer (score 2):

You could spread the single objects and assign them to a new object.

```js
function subtract(object, keys) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(key => ({ [key]: object[key] })));
}

var fruits = { apple: 'a', orange: 'o', mango: 'm', jackfruit: 'j' };

console.log(subtract(fruits, ['mango', 'orange']));
```

Comment: That's clever, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any filter function to filter these items from this object
>   using this array?

Yes, you can use `reduce` method.

```js
let dict = {
  apple: { color: 'red'},
  orange: { color: 'orange' },
  mango: { color:'green' },
  jackfruit: { color: 'yellow' }
}
let array =  ['mango', 'apple' ]

console.log(array.reduce((obj, key) => ({ ...obj, [key]: dict[key] }), {}));
```

Another method is using `destructing` feature.

```js
let dict = {
      apple: { color: 'red'},
      orange: { color: 'orange' },
      mango: { color:'green' },
      jackfruit: { color: 'yellow' }
}
let array =  ['mango', 'apple' ]

console.log((({ mango, apple}) => ({ mango, apple }))(dict));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` loop over the array for which you want to get the value for the key in `fruitsObj`

```js
var fruitsObj = {
  apple: {rate: 100},
  orange: { rate: 200 },
  mango: { rate: 300 },
  jackfruit: { rate: 400 }
}

var filterArray = ['mango', 'apple'];
var res = [];
filterArray.forEach((fruit)=> res.push(fruitsObj[fruit]));
console.log(res);
```

If you want to use `filter` and `map`, you can filter out the keys first and then use `map` to get the value for that keys.

```js
var fruitsObj = {
  apple: {rate: 100},
  orange: { rate: 200 },
  mango: { rate: 300 },
  jackfruit: { rate: 400 }
}

var filterArray = ['mango', 'apple'];
var res = Object.keys(fruitsObj).filter(fruitKey => ['mango','apple'].indexOf(fruitKey) !== -1).map(filterKey => fruitsObj[filterKey]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter data of specific keys like this.

```
var FilteredObjectsByKeys = Object.assign({}, ...['mango', 'apple'].map(x => fruits[x]));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsObj = {
  apple: "Apple",
  orange: "Orange",
  mango: "Mango",
  jackfruit: "jackFruit"
}

var arr = ['mango', 'apple'];

var newObj = {};

arr.filter(item => newObj[item] = jsObj[item]);

console.log(newObj);
```